# resolve NLog instance with unity container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following class:

```
public class TestInjection
{
    private ILogger logger;
    public TestInjection(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        try
        {
            int zero = 0;
            int result = 5 / zero;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "test message", ex);
            Console.WriteLine("logged message from class");
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `Program.cs` I have the code:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<TestInjection>();

var myTestClass = container.Resolve<TestInjection>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("logger", LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()) });
myTestClass.Process();
```

How to resolve `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` with the unity container, if the default constructor of the `Logger` class it's not accessible?

PS: This is my first experience with DI and Unity.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I've done:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ILogger>(
    new InjectionFactory(l => LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()));
container.RegisterType<TestInjection>();

var myTestClass = container.Resolve<TestInjection>(
    new ResolverOverride[]
    {
        new ParameterOverride("logger", container.Resolve<ILogger>())
    });
myTestClass.Process();
```